# AWS RDS oracle python connection

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-rds, cx-oracle

I have launched an RDS Oracle database instance and wanted to connect it using a python code. i did something using cx_oracle but not worked out.
Any suggestions/ help would be great !

Thanks in Advance

```
import cx_Oracle

connstr = 'username/password@testinstance.cycxmhpviuwu.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com:1521/orcl'
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(connstr)
```

Error message I am getting is:

> cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1047: 32-bit Oracle Client library cannot be loaded: "The specified module could not be found"

Comment: can you give details on what "doesn't work" means? error messages etc.?

Comment: cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1047: 32-bit Oracle Client library cannot be loaded: "The specified module could not be found"

i suspect maybe i am trying to establish connection wrongly !

Comment: The message is pretty clear: you need to install the 32-bit Oracle Client libraries (somehow) to continue.  cx_Oracle requires these client libraries in order to be able to connect to Oracle Database.  (If you have 64-bit Python, you would need the 64-bit Oracle client libraries).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to either (a) install the 32-bit Oracle Client libraries or (b) ensure that you are using 64-bit Python and 64-bit cx_Oracle. See the [installation instructions](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Please check , 32 bit/ 64 bit library , and [Installation Guide](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html)

Moreover, you can refer to the below code snippet

```
    from __future__ import print_function
    
    import cx_Oracle
    import boto3
    import base64
    import requests
    import json
    import configparser
    
    def connect_oracle(oracle_arn,oracle_host,oracle_port,oracle_db):
        session = boto3.session.Session()
        client = session.client('secretsmanager','us-west-2')
    
        response = client.get_secret_value(SecretId=oracle_arn)
        data = json.loads(response['SecretString'])
    
        dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn(oracle_host,oracle_port,oracle_db)
    
        conn = cx_Oracle.connect(data['username'],data['password'],dsn_tns)
    
        return conn
    
    
    
    def test_oracle_connect():
    
        #change the variable value as required 
        oracle_arn = 'oracle_arn'
        oracle_host = 'oracle_host'
        oracle_port = 'oracle_port'
        oracle_db = 'oracle_db'
        
        run_rds_test_scripts = 'true'
    
        if run_rds_test_scripts == 'true':
            conn = connect_oracle(oracle_arn,oracle_host,oracle_port,oracle_db)
    
            cur = conn.cursor()
            executed = cur.execute('select count(*) from dba_tables')
            res = cur.fetchmany(numRows=1)
    
            row_number = len(res)
    
            assert row_number == 1
            cur.close()
            conn.close()
        else:
            print('no run')

test_oracle_connect()
```